# KnockoutJS validate only if field is partially complete

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

Looking for a solution to only validating a input field if it's partially complete ie, don't validate if the user has not entered a value. http://jsfiddle.net/2H2Bv/

Would also be interested to see a solution for removing the validation summary message, "Complete missing fields below", at the top when all fields meet their validation requirements ie when all validation messages attached to each input have disappeared AND before the submit button is clicked...

HTML

```
<script id="customMessageTemplate" type="text/html">
    <em class="customMessage" data-bind='validationMessage: field'></em>
</script>

<!-- ko if: displayAlert -->
<p class="customMessage" data-bind="text: validationSummary"></p> <br />
<!-- /ko -->

<fieldset>
    <legend>Details</legend>
    <label>First name:
        <input data-bind='value: firstName' />
    </label>
    <label>Last name:
        <input data-bind='value: lastName' />
    </label>
    <div data-bind='validationOptions: { messageTemplate: "customMessageTemplate" }'>
        <label>Email:
            <input data-bind='value: emailAddress' required pattern="@" />
        </label>
</fieldset>
<br>
<button type="button" data-bind='click: submit'>Submit</button>
<br>
<br> <span data-bind='text: errors().length'></span> errors
```

JS:

```
ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'Invalid.';

ko.validation.configure({
    decorateElement: true,
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null
});

var viewModel =  function() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable().extend({
        minLength: 2,
        maxLength: 10
    });
    this.lastName = ko.observable().extend({
        required: true
    });
    this.emailAddress = ko.observable().extend({ // custom message
        required: {
            message: 'Enter your email address.'
        }
    });
    this.validationSummary = ko.observable("Complete missing fields below:");
    this.displayAlert = ko.observable(false);
    this.submit = function () {
        if (this.errors().length == 0) {
            alert('Thank you.');
        } else {
            this.displayAlert(true);
            this.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    };
    this.errors = ko.validation.group(this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: What do you mean on "partially complete"? In your example all the properies are required what does "partially complete" mean in this case? Can you described step by step how the code in your fiddle should behave?

Comment: By partial I mean, if the user has entered a value then validate that field according to validation criteria with the inputed data, however, if they haven't entered a value then don't validate that field at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the email validation to run once the user has typed something and not be "red" when the page loads.

To do this you need to remove the `required` and `pattern` attribues so your input becomes:

`<input data-bind='value: emailAddress' />`

and to add email validation to your model so your observable becomes:

```
this.emailAddress = ko.observable().extend({ // custom message
     required: {
          message: 'Enter your email address.'
     }, email:true
});
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2H2Bv/1/)

Comment: Almost! Basically it works how I want it with just: 
this.emailAddress = ko.observable().extend({ email:true }); ...but how would this work for other fields?

Comment: I don't understand what you ask. But you can find more info about knockout validation [here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation)

Comment: Basically I'm trying to capture as much correct information from the user as possible with forcing them to complete all the fields. If they've entered data for first name then validate that field but if they haven't entered a value then don't bother validating that field.

Comment: then don't add `required`